# Bad request in RestSharp?

Tags: restsharp

In my `MyServices` project, I have the service in `TestService.svc`.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GenerateMetadata/{FacilityID}")]
    public List<dynamic> GenerateMetadata(string FacilityID)
    {
```

Then in the code to send a request to it. I have:

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void MetadataServiceShouldReturnExpected()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/MyServices/TestService.svc/");

        var request = new RestRequest("GenerateMetadata/{FacilityID}", Method.POST);
        request.AddUrlSegment("FacilityID", "888");
        var response = client.Execute(request);
```

However when I hover over the response content, I found.

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'User Not Authorized for This Action'. See server logs for more details.

The IIS log doesn't have enough information. Just like:

```
     `2015-04-17 19:13:52 ::1 POST /MyServices/TestService.svc/GenerateMetadata/163 - 80 - ::1 RestSharp/105.0.1.0 400 0 0 391`
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it lacks of body parameter.

If this parameter is set, its value will be sent as the body of the request. Only one RequestBody Parameter is accepted – the first one.

The name of the parameter will be used as the Content-Type header for the request.

RequestBody does not work on GET or HEAD Requests, as they do not actually send a body.

If you have GetOrPost parameters as well, they will overwrite the RequestBody – RestSharp will not combine them but it will instead throw the RequestBody parameter away.